# Trouble pushing events to Firebase Analytics in ReactJS with Firebase SDK

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to push events to Firebase Analytics within a ReactJS application using Firebase SDK. Specifically, when I use the logevent function to trigger an API call, there seems to be a delay of about 5 seconds before the function executes. However, during this delay, if a redirect occurs, the event doesn't get captured in the redirect link.

I'm using Firebase Analytics for event tracking in my ReactJS app.
The logevent function is responsible for triggering an API call to push events to Firebase Analytics.
There's a noticeable delay of approximately 5 seconds before the logevent function executes.
When a redirect happens during this delay, the event associated with the logevent function is not captured in the redirected link.
Seeking a Solution:
I'm seeking guidance or suggestions on how to ensure that events triggered by the logevent function in Firebase Analytics are captured, even if a redirect occurs during the delay before the event is pushed.
Thanks